# My reactjs code throws this error no-unused-expression

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to take an input and then display the value of the input using react. Here's a part of my code.
Edit : App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
var c=0;

function withheaderinput()
{
    return 
    (
    <form  onsubmit='withheaderoutput()'>
        Enter your name : <input type='text' id='name'/>
    </form>
    );
}
function withheaderoutput()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('wihheader').innerHTML='';
    return 
    (
        <p>Hello {name}</p>
    );
}
function Withheader()
{
    return 
    (
    <div id='withheader'>
        {withheaderinput()}
    </div>
     );
}
export default Withheader;
```

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Withheader from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

function renderer()
{ReactDOM.render(<Withheader />, document.getElementById('root'));}
renderer();
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

However, I get the no-unused-expression error on the lines containing return statements. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Do not call the functions, write `{withheaderinput}` instead of `{withheaderinput()}` and also you misspelled in: `document.getElementById('withheader')`

Comment: But I do- I call Withheader from my index.js file

Comment: Can you share the whole index.js or app.js, where these functions in

Comment: Updated the description with index.js an app.js files

Comment: where do you call `withheaderoutput`?

Comment: As the form's onsubmit function

Comment: why would U return your form as a function output? And why are you calling it like this {withheaderinput()}? it has to be {withheaderinput}.

Comment: Returning form because the form was to be replaced by an output- thought the program would be modular this way. Tried {withheaderinput}- no result

Answer (score 1):

If I were you and wanted to write the very same thing I would write sth like this(notice in react we don't mess with DOM directly it's all about VDOM): If U wanna see users input value U should try setting a state for that, U wanna use a functional component (stateless component), fine but it seems that U need state so U should use useState Hook instead :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

export default function Withheader(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  function withheaderoutput(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //whatever you wish to do after submittion but if U wanna log the info
    console.log(name);
// And if U still wish somehow to only see the value instead of the form after submission try using conditional render
  }
  return
  (
    <div id='withheader'>
      <form onSubmit={withheaderoutput}>
        Enter your name : <input type='text' value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Functional components are not stateless components if you use `useState()` hook in them

Comment: I know but he wrote a functional component and apparently needs state for his case so I suggested using that hook which will lead to minimal change in his code ; maybe I should rephrase my statement in answer

Comment: Yes, I already edited your answer to make a few corrections, and the edits are awaiting your approval.